# Java exception error

Tags: java

My professor asked me to do the following homework in Java, but I'm getting error while trying to execute the code.

Please take a look at the code and let me know what's causing the error?
The code is saved into Reverse.java file.

```
package javaapplication44;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Reverse {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String Fname[] = new String[4];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n Enter Something: ");
            Fname[i] = s.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println ("*** The String has been Reversed ***");
        for (int i=4; i>0; i--) {
            System.out.println (Fname[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

error text:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>       at javaapplication44.Reverse.main(Reverse.java:14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes start from zero

change

```
 for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
```

to

```
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
```

also, in your second for loop, start the loop from `i=3`

```
  for (int i=3; i>0; i--) {
```

say if your array is of length 4, the last index would be 3.

just remember this:

```
 LastINdexOfAnArray = Array_Length -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

When u take 4 elements array then u have to count less then 4 Not less than and equal 4.
first loop will be conditioned  i< 4

And also the second loop will be conditioned i>3

Hope it will work

Comment: Second loop should be conditioned as i=3

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```
for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
```

...to...

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
```

You're iterating one beyond the size of your array, getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

You also need to account for this in your second loop.